# Ruby Not Installed on Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, asdf-vm

I recently switched from using the native MacOS version of Ruby to downloading a new version of 3.0.2, as a result on When I Run Rails S command on old projects I get this message:

```
Please install a version by running one of the following:

asdf install ruby 2.6.3
```

When I run this command it says that ruby 2.6.3 is already installed. What is going on here? How do I get my Rails project up and running again?

Comment: I installed 3.0.2 with asdf.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `.ruby_version` to the root of the directory? The documentation seems to suggest that this would be preferable for "asdf" so that it can automatically switch your ruby version

Comment: I have not tried that, I'm not sure what you mean however.

Comment: Create a file in the root of the rails project called ".ruby_version" with content of "2.6.3". When you navigate to this directory asdf should switch to that ruby version based on the content of that file

Answer (score 2):

You can set up it as your default with

```
asdf local ruby 3.0.2
```

(or the version you want).

Once the version is active (check with `ruby --version`) you should also install `bundler`:

```
gem install bundler
```

for that specific version of ruby.

Also, because you use a local version of ruby, you need to `bundle exec` it:

```
bundle exec rails s
```